# Using OLEDB for uploading file with Excel 2016

Tags: c#, excel, oledb, excel-2016, office-2016

my application basically accepts an excel file and uploads data to my database which used to work perfect with Excel 2010 with the below code. However we update the system to Excel 2016 and it stopped working for some reason, could you please assist me in what updates I should make to my code please.

This is the current code to connect:

```
 openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
            var fileName = string.Format(openFileDialog1.FileName);

            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook excelWorkbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(fileName, 1, false, 5, "", "", false, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "", true, false, null, false);

var connectionString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + fileName + "; Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;", fileName);
```

Comment: Does this help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37195033/oledb-connection-string-for-excel-2016-in-c-sharp

Comment: still getting problems with this, for some reason it doesn t work all the time

Comment: Is there any pattern to the failure - certain ranges or data types in the selection - or does it fail on the same range on occasions. If the former, have you tried specifying IMEX=1 after the datasource : https://www.connectionstrings.com/excel/.

Comment: Was 2010 32 bit and 2016 64 bit? If so is your provider for 32bit or 64bit? In short, try installing 64bit version of the provider to the computer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Excel 2016 so I can't test it but this should work.

```
private DataTable ReadExcelFile(string sheetName, string path)
{
    using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection())
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        string Import_FileName = path;
        string fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(Import_FileName);
        if (fileExtension == ".xls")
        {
            conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + Import_FileName + ";" + "Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;'";
        }
        if (fileExtension == ".xlsx")
        {
            conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + Import_FileName + ";" + "Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;'";
        }
        using (OleDbCommand comm = new OleDbCommand())
        {
            comm.CommandText = "Select * from [" + sheetName + "$]";
            comm.Connection = conn;
            using (OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter())
            {
                da.SelectCommand = comm;
                da.Fill(dt);
                return dt;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Also, consider doing it this way.

```
OleDb.OleDbConnectionStringBuilder Builder = new OleDb.OleDbConnectionStringBuilder();
Builder.DataSource = "test.xlsx";
Builder.Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0";
Builder.Add("Extended Properties", "Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1");
Console.WriteLine(Builder.ConnectionString);
```

Finally, check out this site about [Excel connection strings](https://www.connectionstrings.com/excel/).

Answer (score 0):

I answered this in a related question, it was due to an upgrade to Office 16: [oledb connection string for excel 2016 in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37195033/oledb-connection-string-for-excel-2016-in-c-sharp/37997141#37997141)

Answer (score 0):

This may be because the install broke or changed the existing version of the `ACE` driver that was registered.  Reinstalling `ACE` may be required to get it working again. Note if the version changed, your connection string may need to be updated

You should be able to see which versions are available on the machine through the registry:

```
HKCR\Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.XX.0
```